# Kafka : Amount of logs consumerd by consumers

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have a file of 493 mb which i want to us for sending logs from producer to consumer, but when i am consuming data,i get only 1/3 of the data available in the producer, What could be the reason for this

Comment: are you telling this just by comparing size? or data?

Comment: yes, i am comparing the size of data consumed

Comment: What if data is pushed by compressing?

Comment: oh is it? Then how can we confirm the exact data has been consumed

Comment: May be for testing purpose why not a simple program to compare both files data.

Comment: also check whether you are doing the [right thing](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/kafka/2-2-x/topics/kafka_performance.html#concept_gqw_rcz_yq) (I understood, you are pushing one large file in one message)

Comment: How can we compare it as the order of messages is also not same

Comment: Also , the no of lines in the 2 files is different